# How can I encrypt Firefox's cookie db?

Tags: firefox, security, encryption

As far as I know, Firefox saves cookies in local DB, I guess it is SQlite. Are there any way to encrypt it with master password, like autofill data? It appears to be important security feature to me (I can encrypt my passwords, but it is useless if an attacker can get my cookies and just use them). I've seen answers like [this](https://superuser.com/a/119502/952566) which suggest logging out/not using "Remember me" feature, but it is pretty hard nowdays since some form of 2FA is basically anywhere.

Comment: I don’t think encryption on this level will help a lot of an attacker is already able to retrieve the file.

Comment: I am 90% Firefox has plans to encrypt stored passwords with the MacOS or Windows user's password in the future.  However, what I might be thinking, is in order to view the passwords in Firefox itself.  *You can protect your passwords currently with a master password.*

Comment: @Ramhound I know about password protection, but it is effectively useless if attacker can get access to cookie file (you don't need passwords if you have cookies)

Comment: @DanielB this way encryption of passwords can be seen useless as well. There are scenarios where it can be useful, like "laptop left in some kind of public place"

Comment: @biryulin04 - How exactly are they going to get your cookies without physical access to your machine?  You can protect that threat by using BitLocker and EFS, and of course, preventing malicious users from using your machine.  There seems to be an easy solution to this threat, *Don't leave your laptop unattended in a public place*, without physical access to your computer your passwords and your cookies are protected.

Comment: There is already an Firefox bug tracker entry on that topic: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1331238 (bugzilla.mozilla.org seem to have some problems at the moment)

Comment: @Robert, the bug you shared was marked as duplicate of 56788. I just left a comment there – pretty shocked about the lack of encryption: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=56788#c10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there any way to encrypt it with master password, like autofill data?

Firefox does not support this function.  However, you can use Encrypted File System (EFS) and Full Disk Encryption (FDE), to protect this data.

> it is effectively useless if attacker can get access to cookie file (you don't need passwords if you have cookies)

If an attacker has unattended physical access to your machine then all the security in the world will not protected your data.  However, by using FDE and EFS, you can protect your data from being copied to another machine.

> It appears to be important security feature to me (I can encrypt my passwords, but it is useless if an attacker can get my cookies and just use them).

I suspect you are putting to much concern into the fact cookies are not encrypted.  **In my personal experience it's not that easy to use a cookie from one machine and use it on another without being prompted for some sort of authentication.**

There seems to be an easy solution to this threat, Don't leave your laptop unattended in a public place, without physical access to your computer, your passwords and your cookies are protected provided you use a Master Password, Encrypted File System, and Full Disk Encryption.